# Necesito cerrar la sesion del usuario logueado al momento de cambiar de pestaña

Tags: asp.net, sesiones

Necesito que al cerrar la ventana del navegador la sesión con la que he iniciado se cierre, porque al iniciar sesión me redirige a la pagina que deseo, pero cuando cierro la ventana y abro mi proyecto en otra ventana del navegador me aparece logueado el mismo usuario.
cerrar sesión con botón si funciona, pero yo necesito que sea al momento de cerrar o cambiar de pestaña

Tengo esta Funcion pero no se donde mandarla a llamar
Public Sub salir()
        Session.Abandon()
        Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""))
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Que tal Jorge, puede utilizar un evento tipo handler de javascript y dentro de el puedes cerrar la seion o limpiar tus variables de sesion, te dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo de como utilizar el evento:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  
        window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            alert("Esta abandonando este sitio, su sesión finalizará");
        };        
</script>
```

En donde se encuentra el alert puedes cambiarlo por una operación ajax y cerrar la sesión del lado del server.